# Distribution of a linear pure-birth process' integral

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, integration, markov-chains

I stumbled across the following random variable, defined as the integral of a linear pure-birth process i.e. a Yule process:

$$
Z_t = \mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_0^t Y_s ds \bigg| Y_t=k , Y_0=1\bigg]
$$
where $(Y_t)_t$ is a Yule process of intensity $\lambda$ and $k$ an arbitrary positive integer.

Are there any results regarding the $Z_t$'s distribution?

Comment: Are you sure you want to condition on $Y_t=k$  rather than $Y_0=k$?

Comment: Yes. Although I should have mentioned that the Yule process starts in $Y_0=1$. I updated the post.

Comment: Where is the random variable here? Are you interested in the conditional expectation of the integral, or in its conditional distribution?

Comment: The random variables are the Yule process $(Y_t)_t$ and the conditional expectation $(Z_t)_t$. I am interested in the distribution of the conditional expectation above. I think intuitively one might compare it to the integral of a Brownian bridge (although BB is not non-negative and increasing).

Comment: The conditional expectation is a deterministic function of $k$.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. Thank you!